# How many Facebook Graph API calls can i do per user token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to call 8000 times the Facebook search API like this one below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/search?access_token=<myaccesstoken>&q=<call_n>&type=<my_type>
```

How many calls can I do? And if it is not possible what would be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting)

> Your app can make 200 calls per hour per user in aggregate. As an example, if your app has 100 users, this means that your app can make 20,000 calls. This isn't a per-user limit, so one user could make 19,000 of those calls and another could make 1,000. This limit is calculated based on the number of calls made in the previous hour.
>
> To avoid rate limiting:
>
> - Spread out queries evenly between two time intervals to avoid sending
>   traffic in spikes.
> - Use filters to limit the data response size and
>   avoiding calls that request overlapping data.
> - Use the rate limiting header to dynamically balance your call volume.

Comment: But i don t undestand. The specification says "....if your app has 100 users..." what does it mean?  How many users are logged in?  But if it is true why a I can make api call after i log-out, that all i need is just user access token.

Comment: In the docs, it reads:


The number of users for your app is calculated as the average number of daily active users plus today's new logins as an estimated value. Apps with a larger number of users may have more accurate rate limiting than apps with a smaller number of users. Apps with a very small number of users may have rate limit issues.